# NodeJS Express server: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have installed typescript in my project and it works fine on the frontend. on the backend I have a node express server. I've started implementing TS there. when I ran the server just now it failed with:

`filename: (req: Request, file, cb) => {`

`SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` (pointing at the `:`)

How can I make TS work on the server?

I've installed `esm` which allows me to use imports, I've also included:
`"module": "commonjs"` in the package.json

how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to use typescript? Or are you trying to rename `req` into `Request`?

Comment: I don’t use typescript yet but filename is not a type, it’s a variable name so wouldn’t you use =?

Answer (score 2):

You have to compile the TypeScript into JavaScript (e.g. with `tsc`) and then run the resulting JavaScript with Node.js (which doesn't have native support for TypeScript).

Alternatively, look at [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node).